# Started a new project in pycharm and installed packages no longer recognized?

Tags: python, pycharm, project

So when I first started with pycharm I installed a few packages: numpy, scipy etc. using pip install in the cmd prompt and everything was fine.

I have recently started a new project in pycharm and now have the following error when trying to use numpy:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'

I'm fairly new to all this so sorry if my question is in the wrong place. I feel like this has something to do with the location where pip has installed the packages but I honestly have no idea where to start looking to begin fixing this. Any advice is welcome, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PyCharm allows to set interpreter (main python, venv etc.)
Look here in 'Setting an existing project interprete'
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html